# Как поменять иконки или их цвет в WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

В **WebStorm** цвет иконки зависит от типа файла

Например:
`js` файлы помечены желтым,
`ts` и `css` голубым,
`jsx` и `less` оранжевым
и тд

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но так как некоторые расширения файлов имеют одинаковый цвет иконки, то их трудно быстро отличить и найти.

Как поменять иконки, или цвет расширения файла  в **WebStorm**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно скачать плагин с другими иконками - например, [Atom Material File Icons](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10044-atom-material-icons) или [Legacy Icon Pack](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10777-legacy-icon-pack-for-2018-2-).

Если эти плагины не устраивают, можно воспользоваться инструкциями по созданию собственных тем - см. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/themes-customize.html#customizing-icons

Answer (score 0):

File > Settings > Appearance&Behavior > Extra Icons

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]